# Spanner Update in Datagrip: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Value of type NUMERIC cannot be assigned to t.quantity, which has type INT64

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, datagrip

I use DataGrip 2023.3 with Cloud Spanner Driver 2.9.9

When I try to edit a number in the results table and then click 'Submit' to persist the changes, I get the error

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Value of type NUMERIC cannot be assigned to
> t.quantity, which has type INT64

Our table definition is

```
create table stock
(
    id                STRING(36) not null
                           constraint PRIMARY_KEY
                           primary key,
    quantity          INT64(19) not null,
    changedAt         TIMESTAMP(35) not null,
);
```

The resulting update statement is

```
UPDATE stock t SET t.quantity = 0 WHERE t.id = '0009e060-7ab3-43de-bbc1-082831fbe3ce'
```

A colleague uses another DB tool and the statement works as expected.

Is there any setting in DataGrip to make this work?

Comment: This issue has been reported here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17889/Cloud-Spanner-Data-type-INT64-is-not-created-correctly

As this jdbc driver is not officially supported, I'd encourage you to upvote for support of google cloud spanner

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4110/Google-Cloud-Spanner-support